# Powershell script doesn't wait on a process to finish

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have this powershell script that performs set of instructions one of which is `Start-Process` an executable. Howerver I do not want any subsequent instruction to be executed until absolutely the exe is finished. So I used

```
Start-Process progname.exe -wait
```

The problem is sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. How can I ensure no subsequent commands are executed until the exe file completes.

Comment: Unless there is a bug in `Start-Process -Wait`, the implication is that the process is sometimes still running, so you need to investigate that. If `-Wait` doesn't work, neither will other methods.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to do this:

```
$Prog = Start-Process cmd.exe -PassThru
do{sleep 1}while(Get-Process -Id $Prog.Id -Ea SilentlyContinue)
```

it will get the process it started, and then sleep until that process is no longer active.

if you run

```
$P=saps cmd.exe -PassThru
for(){Get-Process -Id $P.Id;sleep 1}
```

does it continually return results or errors?

Comment: This as well hangs in the loop and doesn't continue on to the subsequent commands

Comment: @SamGomari are you absolutely sure the process is fully ending?

Comment: yes, because the executable is a standalone simulation model executable that has a finite simulation time. When it ends it spits out a log file. And I do see this file, it is the process that spawned the exec file that doesn't continue with the remaining instructions...which is bizard ?

Comment: @SamGomari see my update, it sounds like it's definitely still hanging on in the background for some reason.

Comment: @colsw Start-Process ... -Wait waits for the exit of the original process *and* any processes spawned by it. The other answers here just wait for the original process to exit.

Answer (score 1):

Use `WaitForExit()` to continue your script only if process is finished

```
$startProc = Start-Process progname.exe -PassThru
$startProc.WaitForExit()
```

Comment: This doesn't do what I described, the process hangs and doesn't continue on to the subsequent commands

Comment: Your program does not close by itself after complete execution?

Comment: It should after it finishes the rest of the instructions. And it did when I used the Start-Process *.exe -wait

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```
$Installer = Start-Process -FilePath “InstallerFile.exe” -ArgumentList “/Switches /Here” -passthru
Wait-Process -InputObject $Installer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

It'll load the installer information into the $Installer variable, and then wait until the process has exited.

I know you said you don't want it to continue until the process exits, but I'll provide the info anyway for anyone else who see's this.
You can also put a timeout on it by using the following on the `Wait-Process` command:

```
Wait-Process -InputObject $Installer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Timeout 30
```

This will cause a 30 second timeout before the script continues, when this interval expires, the command displays a non-terminating error that lists the processes that are still running, and ends the wait.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
Start-Process [programm].exe
while ((get-process -name [programm]).count -eq 0){}
write-host "Program successfully started"
```