# Running PowerShell script in PowerShell runs correctly but errors when running from scheduler

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that calls an executable EMCopy64.exe with a set of variables and command line switches Here is the script:

```
<# 
This script will take values from a CSV file that has a list of items broken into three columns
EXAMPLE
Folder,Source,Destination  
parapps,\\eme-fs01\c$\paraps\paraps,\\eur-pdfs01\c$\vol_paraps   
#>
$copyFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path D:\netapp_copy\csv -Name *.csv
$fileCount = $copyFiles.count

# This is to send the alert emails
$anonUsername = "anonymous"
$anonPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "anonymous" -AsPlainText -Force
$anonCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($anonUsername,$anonPassword)
$fileNameDateTime = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy HH-mm-ss"
$startDateTime = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
$scriptLog = New-Item -Path D:\netapp_copy\csv\scriptlog\$($fileNameDateTime).log
Add-Content -Path $scriptLog -Value "Starting the script at $startDateTime"
Add-Content -Path $scriptLog -Value "Found $($copyFiles.count) files in the directory"
foreach ($cf in $copyFiles) {
    $copyValues = Import-Csv -Path D:\netapp_copy\csv\$cf 
    $DateTime = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-dd-MM-HH-mm-ss"
    $folder = $($copyValues.folder)
    $sour = $($copyValues.Source)
    $dest = $($copyValues.Destination)
    Add-Content -Path $scriptLog -Value "$DateTime Starting copy of folder $folder"
    $log = "D:\netapp_copy\log\$($folder)-$($dateTime).txt"
    $stdout = "D:\netapp_copy\log\$($folder)-$($dateTime).out"
    Add-Content -Path $scriptLog -Value "Log file is $log"
    Add-Content -Path $scriptLog -Value "Error log file is $stdout"
    $copyCMD = "D:\netapp_copy\emcopy64.exe $sour $dest *.* /s /o /de /r:1 /w:1 /c /th 128 /log:$log >>$stdout"
    Add-Content -Path $scriptLog -Value "Command is $copyCMD"
    D:\netapp_copy\emcopy64.exe $sour $dest *.* /s /o /de /r:1 /w:1 /c /th 128 /log:$log >>$stdout
    $erred = get-content $log
    $CheckIfBad = $erred | %{$_ -match " ERROR "}
    if ($CheckIfBad -contains $true) {
        $emailParms = @{
            From = 'Script@file.copy.com'
            To = 'toaddress'
            credential = $anonCredentials
            SmtpServer = 'SMTPServer'
            Subject = "Error in EMCopy64 copy process of $folder"
            Body = "Check the log file $log"
        }
        Send-MailMessage @emailParms -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}
$endDateTime = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
Add-Content -Path $scriptLog -Value "Script finished at $endDateTime"
```

The critical command is:

`D:\netapp_copy\emcopy64.exe $sour $dest *.* /s /o /de /r:1 /w:1 /c /th 128 /log:$log >>$stdout`

The complete command resolves to:
`D:\netapp_copy\emcopy64.exe \\ame-eds02\c$\AME_EDS02_AF001\q_AME_EDS02_AF001 \\nam-pdeds02\c$\AF001 *.* /s /o /de /r:1 /w:1 /c /th 128 /log:D:\netapp_copy\log\AF001-2020-29-09-08-49-31.txt >>D:\netapp_copy\log\AF001-2020-29-09-08-49-31.out`

Or variants of this. When I run it in a PowerShell ISE terminal it runs correctly with no errors. However when I run it from the task scheduler or a command window  get the EMCopy command opening as many windows as there are items in the loop all at once. It is not waiting for the previous command to finish running before running the next.

What must I do to prevent this from happening? I tried the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522819/powershell-script-doesnt-wait-on-a-process-to-finish) but all that resulted in was the command failing in all of the windows because it did not recognize the arguments.

Comment: Is that your executable or third party? Is the error produced by powershell or emcopy64.exe? I found the [source](https://www.csharpcodi.com/csharp-examples/System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_shell(System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo,%20System.Diagnostics.Process)/) of the error message, maybe is helps.

Comment: This is a third party executable. Dell EMC is the owner.

Comment: @marsze, You asked if it was PowerShell or EMCopy64.exe that was throwing the error. From the formatting of the error I believe it is PowerShell echoing the error from EMCopy64.exe

Comment: You should consider to include the full script in your question. Also, which version of powershell are you using? 7-preview? It could actually be a bug in the start-process-functionality (see the link from my other comment) Have you tried Powershell 5 or 6?

Comment: I did not include the script because it works in a PowerShell 7.0.3 terminal. I will try 5 and see if that works.

Comment: OK included script and what happens when I run it in 5.0 from a command prompt. I am running `powershell D:\netapp_copy\FileShareCopy.ps1`